# get value from specific background

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list with background colors in "A" column and value in their ceil is the name of colors.
I want to do that when I select a cell with a background color this will change the value of "C1" value to the value that have in "A" column.

(this is not the my real name of the colors, I have a specific name for each colors.)
Like vlookup but with background colors and in the same ceil.

For example:
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? There is probably a natural solution using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event.

Comment: I tried.. I am not know to really write in VBA...

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the code section of the worksheet :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If dictColours.Exists(.Interior.ColorIndex) Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1").Value = dictColours(.Interior.ColorIndex)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

And add this to a new module, replacing the sheet reference:

```
Public dictColours As Scripting.Dictionary

Sub test()
    Set dictColours = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Set rngTarget = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    Do While rngTarget.Value <> ""
        dictColours.Add rngTarget.Interior.ColorIndex, rngTarget.Value
        Set rngTarget = rngTarget.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of using the conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

elaborating on the very fine solution form Will I'd propose the following alternative code to be entirely put in the code section of the relevant worksheet

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dictColours As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dictColours = GetDictColours(Target.Parent)

    With Target
        If dictColours.Exists(.Interior.ColorIndex) Then
            .Parent.Range("C1").Value = dictColours(.Interior.ColorIndex)
        End If
    End With
End Sub


Function GetDictColours(sht As Worksheet) As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim i As Long

    Set GetDictColours = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Do While sht.Range("A1").Offset(i) <> ""
        GetDictColours.Add sht.Range("A1").Offset(i).Interior.ColorIndex, sht.Range("A1").Offset(i).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Function
```

aside from some stylistic choices (everyone has his own favorites), it should be more simple for the OP to handle, he being (as he himself stated) a total VBA beginner!

Comment: Hve you copied that code in the relevant Worksheet code pane and not in a module one. what is not working exactly? what error is thrown at which code line?

Comment: this is the error: Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: I think Function GetDictColours(sht As Worksheet) As Scripting.Dictionary, this is not in yellow but this is seleced...

Comment: Maybe you have to add a reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library. I'm not by my PC and can't state exact step to accomplish this. If you don't already know ho to do it you can google "vba excel how to add a new library reference"